# Нужна ли запятая перед "после"

Tags: пунктуация

> По другой версии, заикаться мальчик стал от испуга(,) после падения в глубокую яму.

Ставится ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

> По другой версии, заикаться мальчик стал от испуга, после падения в
>   глубокую яму.

Это уточнение, дополнительный член предложения, выделяется запятой.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а нужна запятая в таком предложении: Медики считают, что мальчик стал заикаться  от испуга после падения с высоты.

Comment: Думаю, здесь запятая может как ставиться, так и не ставиться, в зависимости от того, на чем вы делаете смысловой акцент. Если "испуг после падения с высоты" это для говорящего единое цельное обстоятельство произошедшего, то запятая не нужна. Можно даже заменить "после" на "от": "испуг от падения с высоты". Испуг ведь обычно случается не после, а во время чего-либо. Если же говорящий подразумевает прежде всего испуг в целом и затем уточняет его, то "после падения с высоты" будет уточнением, и запятая нужна.

Comment: А почему в заданном предложении Вы определились однозначно? Я тоже считаю, что запятая там нужна, но для этого мне нужно было посмотреть КОНТЕКСТ. Там рассматривались ДВЕ ВЕРСИИ (генетические отклонения и испуг), и тогда обстоятельство действительно имеет уточняющее значение. В моем же предложении уточнение не просматривается, да и структура его  проще, поэтому запятую ставить не хочется.

Comment: Я это всё говорю к тому, что говорящий при выборе смысловых акцентов не так свободен. Если же такая свобода есть, то он свое понимание закладывает в структуру предложения (мы и в устной речи должны понимать, если  там уточнение или его нет). Проверяющий знаки препинания в принципе не должен спрашивать у автора,  какой он смысл вложил в предложение, этот смысл должен считываться со всего текста и со структуры конкретного предложения. Поэтому меня немного огорчил Ваш очень краткий ответ, в котором   альтернативный вариант без запятой вообще не рассматривается.

Comment: "По другой версии" говорит нам о том, что есть и иная версия, т. е. мы имеем что-то еще, а вместе с ним и противопоставление: испуг и что-то другое, поэтому здесь выделяется в первую очередь и главным образом испуг, а затем идет уточнение к нему. Впрочем, Вы и сами уже сказали об этом. Отсюда и не рассматривается альтернативный вариант. Ну и интуитивное восприятие тоже. Не все же в правила упираться.

Comment: У говорящего всегда есть свобода в расстановке смысловых акцентов, а вместе с ним и запятых :)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая здесь факультативна.

Если простая констатация факта, то запятая не нужна.

А если акцентировать причину, то нужна запятая. Это художественный вариант.

В большинстве случаев запятая перед `после` в простых предложениях не ставится.